# session.invalidate method is reloading the same page on back button

Tags: session, servlets

In my project I am using HttpSession for maintaining the user state. when I hit the link to logout servlet and logs out successfully but if I press back button it reloads the profile page again.

LogoutServlet.java

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
session.invalidate();
response.sendRedirect("index.html");
```

LoginServlet.java

```
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("userName",u);
```

Comment: And does the browser really reload the page, or just displays it from the cache? Anyway, to debug further, a bit more code of the profile page (and perhaps also of the login servlet) would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can imagine 3 possible causes :

- you are using a Single Sign On system (something like [CAS](http://jasig.github.io/cas)) and you are automatically reconnected when you close your session => in that case you explictely disconnect from the SSO (not the most common problem)
- the back button of the browser shows a cached version of the page. You can confirm that by asking a full refresh of the page - normally Ctrl-F5 does it but you will find more references on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache) => in that case you cannot do more except controlling the configuration of cache on browser and the caching parameters of the page (HTTP header Expire)
- the URL contains the reference to the user and is publicly accessible : the display is normal => if you do not want that, you should make the page accessible only to logged on users.